# Send keys control + Shift + click in Selenium with Python

Tags: python, selenium

I want to select first 100 elements in a list so I user action chain method.
Please suggest any other method, if any. With the code I used below, I can select elements in the list but I am not able to click any element:

```
for r in range(1, 100):
    r = str(r)
    print r
    row = GlobalVar.Driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/select/option["+r+"]")
    action_chains = ActionChains(GlobalVar.Driver)
    action_chains.key_down(Keys.CONTROL).key_down(Keys.SHIFT).click(row).key_up(Keys.SHIFT).key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: can you share the html code for the same?

Comment: yes. I have taken the screen shot of that

Comment: please refer this [enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5z3P.png

Comment: style="height: 100%;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td align="center" width="25%" style="vertical-align: middle;">
<table cellspacing="3" cellpadding="0" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<tr>
<td align="left" height="100%" style="vertical-align: top;">
<select class="gwt-ListBox" multiple="" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
<option value="u-mbasquez">Basquez, Marilyn</option>
<option value="u-cbatac">Batac, Crystal</option>

Answer (score 0):

It is a select tag, you can go with select class in python.

```
ele = GlobalVar.Driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/select")

select = Select(ele)

for index in range(1, 100):
    select.select_by_index(index)
```

It is not advisable to use absolute xpath. please try to use relative path if possible or other locator types.

Comment: thank you for u are the answer but I want to select using ctrl + shift + click only. because test case is like that

Comment: Do you mean manual test cases?  And is your target to select first 100 option s or following the test step as it is.

Comment: yes, I have to automate the test case so in that the condition is to select first 100 elements in the list using ctrl + shift + then click each element